# TypeScript guarding object property access when keys are known, but accessing with any string

Tags: typescript

[Here is an example of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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%20UBocCeUB6RGhBkoY%20GKElLK1urJRpNZotoeZtvUDoLlarKrrF4b2LgAHF-IZNPubUq3HGuxB%203iE84L5FJL-hTXABCd96SfVl30-VgeTPZdf1zDVzwAi9Jn5E8NmQut5mOFJm2iABpaJFAAdWiTxfWiG9m19G8MCyOCLzEH9f3-X8rxhFBgENO8vAfUhwMPV9ILbL9mIvBCoWhTjuPvGgxzEUdXQbOAcH1LA4DQFkS39LxAy8YMIHA8M4zSTJLBSUA1iTHkgA)

I have an object named `LanguageOptions` with known keys:

```
const LanguageOptions = {
  NB: { kode: "nb", tekst: "Bokmål" },
  NN: { kode: "nn", tekst: "Nynorsk" },
  SE: { kode: "se", tekst: "Samisk" },
  EN: { kode: "en", tekst: "Engelsk" },
} satisfies Record<string, { kode: string; tekst: string }>;
```

I want to access this object with a string, and I want typescript to correctly infer that I have handled all the cases where the string is not present in the object. I have only been able to solve it with either:

```
LanguageOptions[languageUpper as keyof typeof LanguageOptions]
```

Or a typeguard like:

```
function languageInLanguages(language: string): language is keyof typeof LanguageOptions {
  return Object.hasOwn(LanguageOptions, language);
}
```

Neither approach guarantees that I have avoided making any mistakes. With `as keyof typeof LanguageOptions` I'm lying to TypeScript. With the guard, I could return the wrong value (like always true) and get no TS error but a runtime error. My preferred solution would be something like this:

```
if (Object.hasOwn(LanguageOptions, language)) {
  const noGuard = LanguageOptions[languageUpper];
}
```

But that gives the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`. Any suggestions on how to make this fully type safe?

Comment: You can’t; TypeScript doesn’t model “exact types” where only the exact keys mentioned in the definition are allowed to exist. Object types are extendible, so no matter what you can’t convince TS that there won’t be some unknown property. You’d need either https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936 or https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 for this to work. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Please write an answer with the explanation, but could you also mention what approach you recommend? Even if it is not fully type-safe.